# Density of $w\pi + (1-w)\mu$ with respect to $\nu+\lambda$, with $\pi$ Poisson, $\mu$ exponential, $\nu$ counting and $\lambda$ Lebesgue measures

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

**Let $X\sim poisson(5)$**, which means that $X$ is a random variable taking values in $\{0,1,...\}$ with probability mass function $$P(X = x) = e^{-5}\frac{5^x}{x\text{!}}, \,x = 0,1,...$$ if we let $\nu$ denote a counting measure on $\{0,1,2,...\}$, then $$P^X(B) = \int\limits_{B}e^{-5}\frac{x^5}{x\text{!}}dv(x)$$

**Let $Y\sim Exp(1)$**, which means that $Y$ is a random variable taking values in $[0,\infty)$ and $$P(a\leq Y \leq b) = \int\limits_{a}^{b}e^{-1}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)dy, \, a\leq b$$ if we let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then $$P^Y(B) = \int\limits_{B}e^{-1}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)d\lambda(y).$$

**Exercise:** Define the random variable $Z$ by $$Z = \begin{cases} X, \text{with probability}\, w\\
Y, \text{with probability } 1 - w\end{cases}$$ where $w\in[0,1]$. Show that $P^Z = wP^X + (1-w)P^Y$ has density $$w\frac{dP^X}{d\nu}(x)\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{N}}(x) + (1-w)\frac{dP^Y}{d\lambda}(x)\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\backslash{N}}(x),$$ with respect to $\nu + \lambda$.

**Solution:** first note that $P^X \ll \nu + \lambda$ and $P^Y \ll \nu + \lambda$. Hence $P^Z \ll \nu + \lambda$. Now there exists a set $A$ with $\nu(A^C) = \lambda(A) = 0$. Take $A = \mathbb{N}$ so that $A^C = \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{N}$. Now \begin{split} P^X(B) &= \int\limits_{B}\frac{dP^X}{d\nu}(x)d\nu(x) \\&= \int_{B}\frac{dP^X}{d\nu}(x)\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{N}}(x)d\nu(x)\\ &= \int\limits_{B}\frac{dP^X}{d\nu}(x)\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{N}(x)d(\nu + \lambda)(x).
\end{split} Similarly, we get \begin{split}P^Y(B) &= \int\limits_{B}\frac{dP^Y}{d\lambda}(x)d\lambda(x) \\ &= \int\limits_{B}\frac{dP^Y}{d\lambda}(x)\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{N}}(x)d\lambda(x)\\
&= \int\limits_{B}\frac{dP^Y}{d\lambda}(x)\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{N}}(x)d(\nu + \lambda)(x). \end{split} The result now follows by combining the previous results when computing $wP^X(B) + (1-w)P^Y(B)$.

**Questions:**

- Why do we have that $P^X \ll \nu + \lambda$ and $P^Y \ll \nu + \lambda$?
- Why do we have that $\int\limits_{B}\frac{dP^X}{d\nu}(x)\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{N}}(x)d\nu(x) = \int\limits_{B}\frac{dP^X}{d\nu}(x)\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{N}(x)d(\nu + \lambda)(x)$?
- Why do we take $A = \mathbb{N}$ so that $A^C = \mathbb{R}\backslash{N}$?
- Why do we have $P^X(B) = \int\limits_{B}e^{-5}\frac{x^5}{x\text{!}}dv(x)$? Isn't $X$ a discrete random variable? Shouldn't we get a summation instead of an integral?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=(p_n)$ denote the PMF of the Poisson distribution and $f$ the PDF of the exponential distribution, then, for every Borel subset $B$, $$P(Z\in B)=wP(X\in B)+(1-w)P(Y\in B)=w\sum_np_n\mathbf 1_{n\in B}+(1-w)\int_Bf(x)dx$$ that is, $$P^Z=w(p\nu)+(1-w)(f\lambda)$$
Extend $p$ to a function $g$ defined on the real line, by setting $g(n)=p_n$ for every nonnegative integer and $g(x)=0$ for every $x$ not a nonnegative integer. Likewise, define the function $h$ by $h(x)=f(x)$ for every $x$ not a nonnegative integer and $h(n)=0$ for every nonnegative integer $n$.

Then, $h$ is again a PDF of the exponential distribution since, for every Borel subset $B$, $$\int_Bf(x)dx=\int_Bh(x)dx$$ Furthermore, $$g\lambda=h\nu=0$$ because $\{g\ne0\}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ has $\lambda$-measure zero and $\{h\ne0\}=[0,+\infty)\setminus\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ has $\nu$-measure zero, hence $$P^Z=(wg+(1-w)h)(\nu+\lambda)$$ Not sure there is much more to say.